# Fungal or bacterial infestation ? Pachypondium Lamere or Pin Palm

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, plant-recommendations, fungus

I have this Madagascar Pin Palm or Pachypondium Lamerei which has been attacked by some kind of fungal or bacterial infestation.

I've been using an antifungal solution, yesterday was the 3rd application (spraying the solution mixed with water once a week) but it doesn't seem to get any better as new black spots appear on the back of new leaves (see pictures).

I have been using Amystar from Syngenta mixed in a water solution according to instructions from the producer.

Does anyone know what this is and if there is a better solution?

It doesn't have any pests, at least none that I can see and it didn't have a pest infestation before.

I water it every almost 5-7 days and it sits in full sun for about 5-7 hours in a South-West window. The soil is specifically for cactuses/succulents and the pot has a drainage system in which the extra water can spill.

Images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tig6i.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXdG3.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bl9D.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ0d4.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrXhE.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9vDP.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxsFY.jpg

Thanks, 
Radu

Answer (score 2):

Well I would say neither bacterial nor fungal. Reason being that the leaf of Pachypodium is typically tropical in that it is thick with a waxy/shiny/hard coat surface. It's really quite difficult for an infection to get from the outside in. Much more likely for problems to arise on the inside and display signs through the most visible parts later.

Recall that Pachypodium (thick-foot) is like many succulents designed to profit from downpours of rain followed by very dry conditions; it rapidly absorbs water into the trunk and the leaves when it has the chance and hangs onto this moisture as long as possible, feeding it to the growing parts as required. To emulate this in the house you need a fast draining mix like cactus mix which evidently you already have. However your draining system might need a review to see if it is working efficiently. All you really need is a free draining pot standing high so that no water can accumulate in the saucer, and make sure you do not water until the plant has "deflated" quite a lot. Otherwise root rots begin and signs show in the leaves.

Comment: Hmm, while your explanation does make sense, logically, I am doubting the fact that it might have root rot since the stem looks good, the other two stems have been growing and it's constantly growing new leaves. From what I've researched it looks like some kind of fungal infection. I mean that explains the black spots and the fact that they always appear on the backside of the leaf. I've also checked the drainge and water does remain in the saucer quite fast after watering.

Comment: Check the roots by pulling the pot from the plant (tilt sideways); fungus on leaf should show characteristic growth under high magnification?

Comment: So I checked the roots at the top portion and they looked healthy. White and firm. I also accidentally broke some of the more deeper roots and theu were the same, white and firm.

Comment: https://imgur.com/n890VYf

Comment: https://imgur.com/ac278Kc - no mushy or black/brown parts. Soil was almost dry, I did feel some moisture, but it was far from damp, felt mostly cold and dry.